# CiviCRM Resourse URL incorrectly configured in the CiviCRM Admin page

Tags: resource-urls

Unfortunately, I configured the **CiviCRM Resource URL** incorrectly in the Admin Page, instead of writing ***civicrm.root***, I typed "***civicrm_root.url***" and although ***$civicrm_root*** is correctly configured in *civicrm.settings.php* it is not possible now to access CiviCRM as it throws:

*RuntimeException*: Cannot resolve path using "civicrm_root.url" in Civi\Core\Paths->getVariable() (line 140 of C:\Apache24\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\modules\civicrm\Civi\Core\Paths.php).

How can I change now **CiviCRM Resource URL** without accessing the admin user interface?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

1. Try accessing directly using /civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1
2. That setting is written to the database.  You can edit it (or delete it) by looking in the civicrm_setting table, with the variable name="userFrameworkResourceURL".

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed!
Changing that setting in the CiviCRM_Setting table with the variable name="userFrameworkResourceURL" solved the problem.
Many thanks for your help!